# How to create iphone theme apps

Tags: ios, themes

I want to create a theme app ios permit custom wallpaper, icons, other themes... I don't know how to create that type apps. Pro user, help me. Thank so much. (Sorry, i'm   bad English)

Answer (score 0):

I don't pretty sure whether you want to custom your App or custom your iPhone.

If you want to custom the appearance of an app, you may checkout some WWDC session like [Advanced Appearance Customization on iOS](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/?id=216)

If you want to custom a theme in a jailbreaked iOS device. you may need to know WinterBoard.

And try to search it.